What's the aestivation in Onion (Allium cepa)? Is it valvate or imbricate?
In my textbook it's written Liliaceae has valvate aestivation but in a question asked in a popular entrance exam (NEET UG), onion is mentioned to have imbricate aestivation...I am confused.

Both members of Liliaceae (sensu stricto) and Allium can have imbricate aestivation.
I unfortunately couldn't find good images with shareable permissions. But if you look here you can see a photo showing buds where an inner tepal is overlapped on both sides by other inner tepals.
This image is a bit more ambiguous, since some of the key areas are cropped out, but it could be showing valvate aestivation.
If you google "Lilium bud cross section" you'll find several images, most of which nicely show imbricate aestivation. I also found a reference that Lilium philippinense has imbricate aestivation.
However, it's commonly recognized now that Allium is not a part of family Liliaceae or even order Liliales, but a separate order, Asparagales. So, it's not entirely surprising that these groups might have different aestivations.
